# Disable the Gnome screensaver from the command line

Tags: command-line, gnome, screensaver

I would like to disable the screensaver on Centos 6.2 for a single user. I have tried from the GUI, that looked like the easiest way, but it didn't work out, I am not sure why. I am looking for an instruction for the command line or a suitable initialization file. I am using Gnome 2.28.2 on CentOS.